# find this inequality min (a)

Tags: inequality

let $x_{k}\in R$,and $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}=1,n=2m+1,m\in N^{*}$,and

$a\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^2_{k}\right)^3\ge\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}|x_{k+1}-x_{k}|\right)^2\left(n\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^2_{k}-\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\right)^2\right),x_{n+1}=x_{1}$

find the $\min{a}=?$

Comment: The sum $\sum_{k=1}^n |x_{k+1}-x_k|$, the last sub-index will be $n+1$...

Comment: Source?${}{}{}$

Comment: Why writing $(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k)^2$ in the last term if it is $1$?

Comment: @math110 I'm still hoping you could answer julien question, because something does not seems right here.

Comment: because I Homogeneous this inequlaity.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion. :/

$a = \max_{x_1,\cdots,x_n}\dfrac{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}|x_{k+1}-x_k|\right)^2\left(n\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 - \left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)^2\right)}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2\right)^3}$

If we fix the values of $x_1,\cdots, x_n$, we can see we need to maximize the numerator by permute the $x_1,\cdots,x_n$, and the denom will not change.

**Rearrange**

suppose initially $x_1\le x_2 \le \cdots, x_n$, we take a permutation $\pi : \vec{x}\rightarrow \vec{y}$, such that

$y_1\le y_3\le y_5\cdots\le y_{2m+1}\le y_{2m}\le y_{2m-2}\le \cdots \le y_2$,

we shall say this (or reversed version) can maximize the numerator.

Actually, if you take any permutation to this, we can see this will decrease the sum.

---

*Without loss of generality*, we assume our $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ has been arranged in this way.

Which means

$x_1\le x_3\le x_5\cdots\le x_{2m+1}\le x_{2m}\le x_{2m-2}\le \cdots \le x_2$,

Then say the gaps between them is $d_1,\cdots d_{n-1}$, where $d_i$ are non-negative.

$x_3 = x_1+d_1$,

$x_5 = x_1 + d_1 +d_2$,

$\dots$,

$x_4 = x_1 + d_1 + d_2 + \dots +d_{2m-1}$

$x_2 = x_1 + d_1 +d_2 +\dots + d_{2m-1}+d_{2m}$ ,

And $$(2m+1)x_1 + \sum_{i=1}^{2m} (2m+1-i)d_i = 1$$
thus $$x_1 = \dfrac{1-\sum_{i=1}^{2m} (2m+1-i)d_i}{2m+1}\le \dfrac{1}{2m+1}$$ and

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2m} (2m+1-i)d_i = 1-(2m+1)x_1$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} |x_{k+1}-x_k| = d_1 + 2d_{2m} + 3d_2+4d_{2m-1}+\cdots+ (2m)d_{m+1}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 = x_1^2+(x_1+d_1)^2+\cdots+(x_1+d_1+\cdots+d_{2m})^2 = (2m+1)x_1^2 + 2x_1\sum_{i=1}^{2m}(2m+1-i)d_i + \sum_{l=1}^{2m}(\sum_{k=1}^l d_k)^2 $$

Then all the arguments are with $d_1,d_2,\cdots,d_{2m}$, the only requirements for $d_i$ is non-negative.

Comment: I tink this is very ugly! but Thank you all the same.

Comment: @math110 Yes, it is ugly, I do not know how to avoid the permutation part, though.